# Copy constructor motivation - why my program don't crash?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

I learned that one of the motivation for copy constructor using is to avoid of the follow crash in the program  -

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Employee {
public:
    Employee(int ID,char const * name){...};
    ~Employee(){...};

    // Methods
    void Print();

private:
    // members
    int m_ID;
    char* m_name;
};

void MyFunc(Employee emp) {

    cout << "in MyFunc \n ";

}

int main() {
    Employee One(1,"Garen Torosian");

// calling copy constructor
    MyFunc(One);

    cout << "In the end of main \n";

// Here the program crashes!
    return 0;
}
```

as you can see the program should be crash before the `return 0;` , but when I run that program it works fine and terminated ok , why ?

**Edit :** In this case the program indeed crash  -

```
// Employee.h
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Employee {
public:
   Employee(int ID, 
                   const char* name);
  ~Employee();

  // Methods
  void Print();

private:
  // members
  int   m_ID;
  char* m_name;
};
```

---

```
// Employee.cpp
#include "Employee.h“

Employee::Employee(int iID, const char *name){ // Ctor
  cout << "Constructor called" << endl;
  m_ID = iID;
  m_name = new char [strlen(name) +1];
  strcpy(m_name, name);
  Print();
}
void Employee::Print() { // Print
cout << "ID: " << m_ID << ",Name:” << m_name
<< " ,Address(pointer):0x" << hex << (int) m_name<< endl;
}
Employee::~Employee() { // Dtor
  cout << "Destructor called"<<endl;
  Print();
  delete [] m_name;
  m_name=NULL;
}
```

---

```
void MyFunc(Employee emp) {

  cout << "in MyFunc \n ";    

}

int main()
{
    Employee One(1,"Eli Rachamim");

// calling copy constructor
MyFunc(One);

cout<< "In the end of main \n“;

// Here the program crashes! 
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Depends on what's in your ctor and dtor... also, UB means *anything* can happen, even simply working.

Comment: I guess that there is `delete this->m_name()` in destructor and the crash is due to "double free detected".

Comment: @Greg I think you nailed it.  That with an allocation in the constructor code.  Excellent psychic debugging.

Comment: @Xeo you right  , I tried to work less so I didn't implement all the dtor as in the example of my lecture . In the full example of the program it indeed crash .

Comment: I think you really should not think of programming "in order to avoid a crash". That's a really unhelpful mental model. If there's a crash, that's a result of a programming error, and crashes will disappear the more confident a programmer you become.

Comment: @Kerrek SB : I just wanted to see example for why using copy ctor , that not my thinking when I programming .

Comment: At the end of the destructor, remove `m_name=NULL;`. The object is being destroyed; setting this pointer to NULL doesn't do anything useful. (This has nothing to do with the crash)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `d-tor` is like

```
~Employee(){ delete[] name; }
```

and you alloc memory for your `char*` pointer, and you have no `copy c-tor`, than `copy c-tor` generated by compiler, that do `memberwise-copy`, will be called when you copy object. So, there will be `double-free`, that in most cases give you `memory dump` (in real calling destructor to already destructed object is `UB` and calling `delete[]` on already deleted object is also `UB`). But if you don't work with memory - `copy c-tor`, generated by compiler works well.

**EDIT.**

So, your second example demonstrates call of `d-tor` to allready destructed object and also `double-free`.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think it should crash?

C++ has the unfortunate feature of supplying an automatically-generated copy-constructor if you don't provide one, and your MyFunc() doesn't really do anything that would get screwed by that auto-generated copy.

Comment: `C++ has the unfortunate feature of supplying an automatically-generated copy-constructor` not in c++11 , you can simply `delete` whatever function you want :)